# Bind ImageAwesome Object in WPF from a ViewModel Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, font-awesome

I'm pretty new to WPF and could really do with some help.
Is there anyway to bind an `ImageAwesome` object ([Font-Awesome](https://github.com/charri/Font-Awesome-WPF)) from a ViewModel property? As it stands, my ViewModel on instantiation creates an `ImageAwesome` object which is then accessible using the property `SpinIcon`.

**ViewModel**

```
 public class DefaultPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private ImageAwesome _spinIcon;


    public DefaultPageViewModel()
    {
        _spinIcon = new ImageAwesome();
        _spinIcon.Icon = FontAwesomeIcon.Spinner;
        _spinIcon.Height = 10;
    }

    public ImageAwesome SpinIcon {

        get
        {
            return _spinIcon;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != _spinIcon)
            {
                _spinIcon = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SpinIcon");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I can bind the individual properties of `SpinIcon` as shown below but this would cause of a lot of duplication of code which I'm trying to avoid.

**UserControl**

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
        <default:DefaultPageViewModel x:Key="DefaultVM" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ImageBrush" Color="LightBlue" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <fa:ImageAwesome  Icon="{Binding SpinIcon.Icon, Source={StaticResource DefaultVM}}"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SpinIcon, Source={StaticResource DefaultVM}}" />
```

Comment: I did not realise you could do that! Works great thank you!